# How do I run a macro on word when I open a specific filename

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document (.doc) that is sent to me daily.  I want to run a macro when this document is opened but only on this document, not others.  It has the same name every time. How can I detect if this is the document that was opened before I run the macro. Thanks!

Comment: Check the document name in the macro.

Comment: So is there some sort of IF statement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code into a Module in your Normal template. Modify it to test for the name of the document you open everyday.

As long as Word is already open, to even a blank unnamed document, this routine will run when you open, from Word, the daily document. You can add to this routine a call to your custom macro.

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    If ActiveDocument.Name = "MyTest.docx" Then
        MsgBox "Hi I've Been Opened"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rich! That did it.